# Xcode 5.1.1 together with xCode 6.1.1 - simulators deleted

Tags: macos, xcode, xcode-simulator

I had Xcode 6.1.1 installed together with the iOS8 simulators but I need to be able to test websites with iOS7 also so I installed Xcode 5.1.1 also and named it to this. (I also renamed Xcode 6.1.1 to that instead of just Xcode).

After that I got all iOS7 simulators in Xcode 5.1.1 working. But now all simulators from Xcode 6.1.1 are gone! When I try to add them back it just loads for a while and then nothing happens. What should I do?

I need iOS7 and iOS8 simulators to test with, preferably on the same computer and without any virtual machine (don't have disk space).

[image: How it looks when I start iOs8 simulator]
[image: This just loads and nothing happens]

I have Mavericks on a Mac Book Pro Retina. Software OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need both versions of Xcode in order to test with iOS7 and 8 simulators. With the latest version you will be able to test in both simulators. You just need to go to Preferences → Downloads and download the iOS 7.1 Simulator. Then you can define simulators with that version on your devices window.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Alright I can indeed download iOs7 simulators in xCode6.1.1 it seems but how do I restore the iOs8 simulators then? They are all gone.. https://www.dropbox.com/s/2uluny7jedmxvwv/Screenshot%202015-02-03%2014.00.02.png?dl=0

Comment: Once downloaded, go to Window → Devices and tab the `+` in the bottom left of the screen. Then select name, device type, iOS version and accept. Xcode will create the simulator for you.

Comment: ``When I try to add them back it just loads for a while and then nothing happens. What should I do?``

Comment: Delete both Xcode versions installed, reinstall (don't forget this) and then install the latest available Xcode (6.1.1). Should work.